# Ruby on Rails 4: Installing GEM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, wysiwyg, font-awesome

I am trying to install my first gem in Ruby, but am having problems with it working.  I am not quite sure where I am going wrong, I am following the directions of the gem step by step.  I am using Cloud9 for my ide.

The gem I am trying to install is the: wysiwyg-rails gem

I add the following line to the gem file:

```
gem 'wysiwyg-rails',        '1.2.5'
```

then I add the following to the application.css file so it looks like:

```
/*
 *= require froala_editor.min.css
 *= require froala_style.min.css
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

And finally I add the require .js file to the application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require froala_editor.min.js
//= require plugins/tables.min.js
//= require_tree .
```

I run bundle install and then restart the server.  When I try to load the page, I get the error: couldn't find file 'font-awesome'

However, i can see that font-awesome is installed

```
Using font-awesome-rails 4.2.0.0
```

If I remove the  *= require font-awesome from the application.css, it starts up without any errors.  When I view the source code, I can see the css and js files ( froala_editor) load up, but font-awesome is not one of them.  Is there a step that I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the problem is very strange,the reason is unknown,but i resloved in my program,just add "font-awesome-rails" gem.

```
gem "font-awesome-rails"
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried installing with `font-awesome-less` or `font-awesome-sass` gems to get them up and running?

It seems you are running without any `sprockets` (asset-pipeline). Add any of  those gems, it probably run fine when serving `rails s`.

After `bundle install`, go to `application.css` and write this code as it follows:

```
@import "font-awesome-sprockets"
@import "font-awesome"
```

Hope that helps.